# Fire Textbox.TextChange event without a button click

Tags: asp.net

I want to call Textbox.OnTextChange event without having to click a submit button or any button.  How can I do this?  As I enter text in the textbox, I want the ontextchange event to fire.

I would elaborate this further.I've a function for validating my entry in textbox which I'm calling ontextchange property.Now this function should be called without me changing focus from my textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` , `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events for this.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Example :

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onKeyPress="javascript:alert('Key Pressed');"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set `AutoPostBack` to `true` on the textbox control. when the client side `change` event fires (when the focus changes from the textbox to something else), the page will do a postback automatically.

Comment: Will it fire when I make a entry in the textbox..or will it need a button click or some kind of other action

Comment: It will fire when your cursor leaves the textbox with AutoPostBack

Comment: If i want to do without changing focus from the textbox,is there a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want a postback:
You want to use the onkeypress or onkeyup javascript event to run the __doPostBack javascript method. __doPostPack has some parameters you will need to look up on msdn

Otherwise just use the onkeypress or onkeyup javascript event to do whatever else it is you need with javascript.